# Android MediaPlayer not displaying video properly when switched from one TextureView to another?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, textureview

I'm using Android's MediaPlayer which I want to use in two different TextureViews, which are of different size. I use the same MediaPlayer for both, by calling `mediaPlayer.setSurface(surface)` to switch from one to the other. When my app switches from one to the other, however, small videos are not displayed properly. They look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Hr3L.png), where the green parts of the video should not be there.

How come the mediaplayer shows different things in different textureviews? How do I fix this?